# SQL Where clause span of dates

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using java, eclipse, and JDBC.

I have 3 tables (`company`, `priceVolume`, `dividend`), of which `priceVolume` contains a string called transdate (*the date of a stocks value split into several different categories, IE. openValue, CloseValue, averageValue...*). In all of my tables, the primary key is `Ticker` (*the stock ticker for a company*).

I also have a attribute in company called Industry, which tells me what industry a stock comes from.

I have a span of days, for example 09.25.2001 to 02.28.2012 for one of them, which I want to get the values from priceVolume if the company is in the selected Industry.

I have this Query, and I don't know how to phrase to WHERE clause to give me this span and only this span. If the type was a date type, I think I'd know how to phrase it. Currently however, as a string, I have no idea. I also have no control over the database, just reading from it.

```
ResultSet rsTickers = stat.executeQuery("SELECT Ticker, OpenValue, CloseValue,
TransDate FROM company NATURAL JOIN pricevolume WHERE industry = " + GivenIndustry + "
GROUP BY ticker");
```

I currently have my program set up so that it just gives me all of rows who's industry matches the given industry and I just sort through them in my program (I throw out all of the one's who aren't in the span). It works, but I feel it's really ineffective. So now I want to limit my Query to just the transDates which fit my criteria.

And I just want to see how to do it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast to `datetime` and check like this

```
ResultSet rsTickers = stat.executeQuery("SELECT Ticker, OpenValue, CloseValue,
TransDate FROM company NATURAL JOIN pricevolume WHERE industry = " + GivenIndustry + "
AND CAST(transDates AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '2001-9-25' AND '2012-2-28' 
GROUP BY ticker");
```

Comment: Not quite, he'll get burned for months 11 and 12, which sort like January, yes?  edit - I'd probably consider casting the two string dates also; then the formatting isn't an issue.  That's a groovy idea.

Comment: Can I say ('2001-9-25' AS DATETIME)?

Comment: You can probably say `cast('2001-09-25' as DATETIME)`   Try it and report back.

Comment: By casting `transDates` to `datetime`, the rest should cast automatically.

Comment: I seem to be getting a null set. I'll try it without Ennis's secondary casts.

Comment: Never mind, I'm using old code where the previous statement was select * and I was trying to access a column which wasn't in the table. This is working and I'm a derp. Thank you for the help  shredder and Ennis.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add a `BETWEEN` clause:

```
ResultSet rsTickers = stat.executeQuery("SELECT Ticker, OpenValue, CloseValue,
TransDate FROM company NATURAL JOIN pricevolume WHERE
transdate between ? and ? and 
industry = " + GivenIndustry + "
GROUP BY ticker");
```